# How can I identify a font from an image and use it on my website?

Tags: fonts

I'm not able to reproduce this character in HTML.

[image]

It is a 'I', I'm not sure what font to apply to have it look like the image.

Comment: As identified in @MikeCiffone's answer, this is the standard ['calligraphic math'](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_fonts#Capital_letters-only_font_typefaces) font provided with Computer Modern for documents compiled using [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX), a typesetting system widely used in certain academic disciplines. However, it is worth pointing out that from a typography point of view it is not designed for continuous text (just for single letters within math expressions) and will look really bad in that context. There are also no lowercase letters provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several websites that have font-detection tools. Simply upload the image of your font and it will detect close matches. Just search "detect font from image" and you'll find them. Some work better than others.

Here are some typefaces with similar `I` characters:

**jsMath-cmsy10**

[image]

**Unscriptedness**

[image]

You can find them on [WhatFontIs.com](https://www.whatfontis.com/) and download for personal use.

Once you have the files you'll load them in your CSS like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CustomWebFont';
  src:  url('theFont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('theFont.woff') format('woff');
}
```